# PHP Loop inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to work out how to do a normal php or WP loop inside a javascript function and I cannot work out the correct solution. Below is where I am currently at, as I wish for the available Tags to be those that fall under a certain post type, or even just a  normal PHP loop.

EDIT/UPDATE: I am trying to output an entire loop of page titles so I do not need to update the auto-complete when users searching, as it will take it directly from page titles.

UPDATE 2: The mission of the below is to created a comma separated value of page titles.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    <?php query_posts('post_type=uc_university'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    "<?php the_title(); ?>",
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
      "Search"
    ];
    $( "#s" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: What if the page title contains `"` ? Better use `var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode(<function to get ALL tags here>); ?>`

Comment: Generally speaking, functions don't tend to `echo` a result, but `return`. You may need `<?php echo the_title(); ?>`

Comment: Does `the_title();` output content ? if so you should put : `echo the_title();`

Comment: Why not do it all in PHP, and `echo` the JS?

Comment: JavaScript is client-side, PHP is server-side. Are trying to generate JavaScript code with PHP?

Comment: you know that PHP isn't a dynamic language, right? It won't run after the page is loaded.

Comment: You should include the current output and the expected output, too.

Comment: I have just edited question, I did not that PHP isn't a dynamic language, I am trying to create a list inside the variable of availableTags so I do not need to manually input the list.

Comment: I'll put my answer as a comment instead, and delete the answer as someone apparently didn't think it qualified: You should try and run your PHP code along outside the javascript so see that it generates the output you desire. 
As stated in several questions on Stackoverflow already, mixing language X in language Y [is considered horrible practise][1].

It would be better to have a data endpoint that you can call from Javascript via Ajax. 

  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

Comment: Hi @Bakkelun thanks for your reply. I do know mixing the two but how would I out put a PHP value as inside a variable?

Comment: JavaScript `var foo = <?php echo $foo; ?>` which means that `$foo` has to mean something server-side before it is compiled and sent to the browser.

Comment: Could you elaborate what the "availableTags" variable will have as example data? A comma separated string? (i.e: "value1","value2","value3".)? If you setup an endpoint that serves this data and call it via Ajax (return it as JSON), you can get that data inside your "source" variable.

Comment: Hi @bakkelun - that's exactly my mission. As this string will be a collection of values. How would I load these comma separated string as PHP thought AJAX?

Comment: I would suggest you google jquery Ajax (if jQuery is what you're using) and then point the url to say localhost/test.php (or wherever your test endpoint would be. Now, this test.php could simply generate all the values (probably json_encode a data array) you need and then echo it. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and give it a whirl. Edit: Here is someone's whose done exactly that: http://www.lennu.net/2012/06/25/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response/